# Problemas para baixar o angular cli pelo terminal devido ao provedor de internet?

Tags: angular, windows, proxy

Estou com um problema (eu estou usando momento o windows 10) que não consigo solucionar.
Quando estou usando a internet aqui na minha casa e dou o comando
 `npm install -g @angular/cli@x.x.x`

o terminal trava e não baixa nada, 
já tentei de tudo....

Ai fui na casa do vizinho que usa outro provedor de  internet e o comando funciona na hora.

Como devo solucionar esse problema definitivamente para poder baixar os pacotes do angular na minha maquina estando eu na minha casa(Que possui uma internet inclusive mais eficaz que a do vizinho)?

Creio que deva ser um problema de proxy(pode ser que eu esteja errado), não tenho ideia de como proceder para configurar o proxy...

Comment: Você usa proxy na sua rede?

Comment: Apenas o pacote do CLI, mais nenhum outro, nem mesmo os outros pacotes do Angular?

Comment: Olha, talvez uma vpn ajude, mas isso não deveria acontecer.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Não, eu não uso proxy.

Comment: @Costamilam Sim depois que eu fui na casa do vizinho e baixei oangular cli  e voltei para casa instalei por exemplo o bootstrap e o jquey via npm no projeto angular

Comment: @EdwardRamos  Obrigado vou procurar aprender a usar uma vpn aqui e tentar.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe O meu provedor é a Brisanet , sinceramente não sei se ele tem o DNS reverso, como nós podemos descobrir isso?

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Amanha tentarei fazer isso , por que agora eu estou fora de minha casa e só estou por lá amanha, pode deixar que eu tentar fazer tudo que você indicou.Muito obrigado